# Android Webview | Facebook login page is not loading at fb login button click in second time

Tags: javascript, android, facebook, webview

I am using website url in webview. when we click on fb/g+ button for login/signup at first time then it's open fb/g+ login page fine and do authorize proper. after logout, when we try to click again on same buttons then fb/g+ login page is not launching. it will work in second click.

What can be issue? Kindly confirm.

Thanks
Gaurav

Comment: Any errors in your logcat?

Answer (score 0):

are you calling fb's logout method after confirming the user with facebook.